# MongoDB aggregation query

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongoDb 2.6.4 and still getting an error:

```
uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)",
    "code" : 16389,
    "ok" : 0,
    "$gleStats" : {
        "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(1422033698000, 105),
        "electionId" : ObjectId("542c2900de1d817b13c8d339")
    }
}
```

Reading different advices I came across of saving result in another collection using $out.  My query looks like this now:

```
db.audit.aggregate([
{$match: { "date": { $gte : ISODate("2015-01-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    $lt : ISODate("2015-01-23T00:00:00.000Z")
                    }
                }
            },

{ $unwind : "$data.items" } ,
{
$out : "tmp"
}] 
)
```

But I am getting different error:
uncaught exception: aggregate failed:

```
{"errmsg" : "exception: insert for $out failed: { lastOp: Timestamp 1422034172000|25, connectionId: 625789, err: \"insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: duties_and_taxes.tmp.agg_out.5.$_id_  dup key: { : ObjectId('54c12d784c1b2a767b...\", code: 11000, n: 0, ok: 1.0, $gleStats: { lastOpTime: Timestamp 1422034172000|25, electionId: ObjectId('542c2900de1d817b13c8d339') } }",
    "code" : 16996,
    "ok" : 0,
    "$gleStats" : {
        "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(1422034172000, 26),
        "electionId" : ObjectId("542c2900de1d817b13c8d339")
    }
}
```

Can someone has a solution?

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to the `$unwind` step in your pipeline.

When you `unwind` by a field having `n` elements, `n` copies of the same documents are produced with the same `_id`. Each copy having one of the elements from the array that was used to `unwind`. See the below demonstration of the records after an `unwind` operation.

Sample demo:

```
> db.t.insert({"a":[1,2,3,4]})

WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.t.aggregate([{$unwind:"$a"}])

{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c28dbe8bc2dadf41e56011"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c28dbe8bc2dadf41e56011"), "a" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c28dbe8bc2dadf41e56011"), "a" : 3 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c28dbe8bc2dadf41e56011"), "a" : 4 }
>
```

Since all these documents have the same `_id`, you get a duplicate key exception(due to the same value in the `_id` field for all the un-winded documents) on insert into a new collection named `tmp`.

> The pipeline will fail to complete if the documents produced by the
>   pipeline would violate any unique indexes, including the index on the
>   _id field of the original output collection.

To solve your original problem, you could set the [allowDiskUse](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) option to true. It allows, using the disk space whenever it needs to.

> Optional. Enables writing to temporary files. When set to true,
>   aggregation operations can write data to the _tmp subdirectory in the
>   dbPath directory. See Perform Large Sort Operation with External Sort
>   for an example.

as in:

```
db.audit.aggregate([
{$match: { "date": { $gte : ISODate("2015-01-22T00:00:00.000Z"),
                    $lt : ISODate("2015-01-23T00:00:00.000Z")
                    }
                }
            },

{ $unwind : "$data.items" }] ,  // note, the pipeline ends here
{
  allowDiskUse : true
});
```

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions?           Unfortunately with allowDiskUse : true I am getting the same original error   Error("Printing Stack Trace")@:0
()@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:37
([object Array],[object Object])@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:866
@(shell):10

uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)",
 "code" : 16389,
 "ok" : 0,
 "$gleStats" : {
  "lastOpTime" : Timestamp(1422046336000, 21),
  "electionId" : ObjectId("542c2900de1d817b13c8d339")
 }
}

Comment: @NewMongoDBUser Why do you want to unwind the array items? Can you explain your use case a bit. We can think of other possible solutions which avoid the `$unwind` operation.

Comment: I need to load data into mySql and each array element will be in the separate row in the rdbms.

Comment: You could better write the `items` split on the client side, since `$unwind` takes a bit of toll when the number and size of the documents is quiet huge.

Comment: i am trying to use PDI kettle for it and seems stuck with this problem